# What is wrong with my MIPS code (arrays)?

Tags: mips

Well I have to convert

```
# j = 0
# x = a[j+k]
# a[j+k] = a[j]
# repeat n-1 times
#   j = (j+k) mod n
#   m = (j+k) mod n
#   y = a[m]
#   a[m] = x
#   x = y
# end repeat
```

to MIPS code. So far, I've come up with this but it prints out incorrect output. Any help?

```
         .data
         .align 2
head1:   .asciiz "\n\nThis program reads a list of integers into an array, and then"
head2:   .asciiz "\nshifts the array to the right with wrap around."
head3:   .asciiz "\nThe list is terminated by a negative integer."
prompt1: .asciiz "\nEnter the shift amount first: "
prompt2: .asciiz "\nEnter array numbers (negative to end)"
newline: .asciiz "\n"
         .text
         .globl main
main:    
# print the prompt messages      See appendix B of P&H or chapter 4 of Britton
         li   $v0, 4           # $v0 = print_string system call code
         la   $a0, head1     # $a0 = address of first prompt
         syscall               # print first prompt
         li   $v0, 4           # $v0 = print_string system call code
         la   $a0, head2     # $a0 = address of second prompt
         syscall               # print second prompt
         li   $v0, 4           # $v0 = print_string system call code
         la   $a0, head3     # $a0 = address of third prompt
         syscall               # print third prompt
# Main program - calls read, rearrange and print functions
         li   $v0, 4           # $v0 = print_string system call code
         la   $a0, prompt1     # $a0 = address of fourth prompt
         syscall               # print fourth prompt
         li   $v0, 5           # $v0 = read_int system call code
         syscall               # read an integer - n
         move $a2, $v0         # $a2 = separation point for rearranging array
         li   $v0, 4           # $v0 = print_string system call code
         la   $a0, prompt2     # $a0 = address of fifth prompt
         syscall               # print fifth prompt
         li   $a0, 0x10000000  # $a0 = base address of array = 10000000 (hex)         
         jal  reada            # read numbers into array
         move $a1, $v0         # $a1 = number of ints read - size of array
         jal  shift            # shift the array to the right
         jal  printa           # print numbers from array to screen
# Call system exit
         li   $v0, 10          # $v0 = exit system call code
         syscall               # halt program execution

# Algorithm for reading numbers into an array
reada:   move $t0, $a0         # $t0 = base address of array
         move $t1, $zero       # $t1 = counter = 0
read:    li   $v0, 5           # $v0 = read_int system call code
         syscall               # read an integer - n
         slt  $t2, $v0, $zero  # if n < 0 then stop reading
         bne  $t2, $zero, exit # exit procedure and return to caller
         sw   $v0, 0($t0)      # a[i] = n
         addi $t1, $t1, 1      # i = i + 1
         addi $t0, $t0, 4      # $t0 = address of a[i + 1]
         j    read             # go back up and read another integer
exit:    move $v0, $t1         # return number of integers read into array
         jr   $ra              # return to calling routine

# Algorithm for printing numbers from an array
printa:  move $t0, $a0         # $t0 = base address of array
         move $t1, $zero       # $t1 = counter = 0
print:   beq  $t1, $a1, exitp  # if (array index = array size), then exit
         lw   $t2, 0($t0)      # $t2 = a[i]
         li   $v0, 4           # $v0 = print_string system call code
         la   $a0, newline     # $a0 = address of newline character
         syscall               # print new line
         li   $v0, 1           # $v0 = print_int system call code
         move $a0, $t2         # $a0 = a[i]
         syscall               # print a[i]
         addi $t1, $t1, 1      # i = i + 1
             addi $t0, $t0, 4      # $t0 = address of a[i + 1]
         j    print            # go back up and print another integer
exitp:   li   $v0, 4           # $v0 = print_string system call code
         la   $a0, newline     # $a0 = address of newline character
         syscall               # print new line
         jr   $ra

# Algorithm for rearranging array

# j = 0
# x = a[j+k]
# a[j+k] = a[j]
# repeat n-1 times
#   j = (j+k) mod n
#   m = (j+k) mod n
#   y = a[m]
#   a[m] = x
#   x = y
# end repeat

# Register usage
# $a0 = base address of array
# $a1 = n, size of array
# $a2 = k, the shift amount


shift:    li $t3, 0          #j = 0
          lw $t3, 0($a0)     #load the value of $a0 in to j
          add $t3, $t3, $a2  # j = j+k
          sw $t3, 4($a0)     # store the new value of j in to $a0

repeat:   beq $a1, $zero, end
          sub $a1, $a1, 1      #n = n-1
          add $t4, $t3, $a2    #j+k
          div $t4, $a1         #divide (j+k) by n
          mfhi $t5        

          move $t5, $t3        #j = (j+k) mod n

          add $t4, $t5, $a2    #j+k
          div $t4, $a1         #divide (j+k) by n
          mfhi $t5             #move rem into t2
          move $t5, $t3        #m = (j+k) mod n
          sw $t3, 4($a0)
          jr $ra
          lw $t3, 0($a0)
          b repeat

end:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lw $t3 after jr $ra won't ever be come out.